# Using PyMEL to set the "Alpha to Use" attribute in an object of class psdFileTex

Tags: maya, pymel

I am using Maya to do some procedural work, and I have a lot of textures that I need to load into Maya, and they all have transparencies (alpha channels). I would very much like to be able to automate this process. Using PyMEL, I can create my textures and hook them up to a shader, but the alpha doesn't set properly by default. There is an attribute in the psdFileTex node called "Alpha to Use", and it must be set to "Transparency" in order for my alpha channel to work. My question is this - how do I use PyMEL scripting to set the "Alpha to Use" attribute properly?

Here is the code I am using to set up my textures:

```
import pymel.core as pm

pm.shadingNode('lambert', asShader=True, name='myShader1')
pm.sets(renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True, name='myShader1SG')
pm.connectAttr('myShader1.outColor', 'myShader1SG.surfaceShader', f=True)
pm.shadingNode('psdFileTex', asTexture=True, name='myShader1PSD')
pm.connectAttr('myShader1PSD.outColor', 'myShader1.color')
pm.connectAttr('myShader1PSD.outTransparency', 'myShader1.transparency')
pm.setAttr('myShader1ColorPSD.fileTextureName', '<pathway>/myShader1_texture.psd', type='string')
```

If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With any node, you can use `listAttr()` to get the available editable attributes. Run `listAttr('myShaderPSD')`, note in it's output, there will be two attributes called 'alpha' and 'alphaList'. Alpha, will return you the current selected alpha channel. AlphaList will return you however many alpha channels you have in your psd.

**Example**

```
pm.PyNode('myShader1PSD').alphaList.get()
# Result: [u'Alpha 1', u'Alpha 2'] #
```

If you know you'll only ever be using just the one alpha, or the first alpha channel, you can simply do this.

```
psdShader = pm.PyNode('myShader1PSD')
alphaList = psdShader.alphaList.get()
if (len(alphaList) > 0):
    psdShader.alpha.set(alphaList[0])
else:
    // No alpha channel
    pass
```

Remember that lists start iterating from 0, so our first alpha channel will be located at position 0.

Additionally and unrelated, while you're still using derivative commands of the maya.core converted for Pymel, there's still some commands you can use to help make your code read nicer.

`pm.setAttr('myShader1ColorPSD.fileTextureName', '<pathway>/myShader1_texture.psd', type='string')`

We can convert this to pymel like so:

`pm.PyNode('myShader1ColorPSD').fileTextureName.set('<pathway>/myShader1_texture.psd')`

And:

`pm.connectAttr('myShader1PSD.outColor', 'myShader1.color')`

Can be converted to:

`pm.connect('myShader1PSD.outColor', 'myShader1.color')`

While they may only be small changes, it reads just the little bit nicer, and it's native PyMel.

Anyway, I hope I have helped you!